# Convert JSON to array without key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, sequelize.js

I have a query to return a column from the database which gets return the following result:

```
[
{
    "tenantName": "H&M"
},
{
    "tenantName": "McDonalds"
}
]
```

However, I want to use the result to create an array that only has the names:
["H&M", "McDonalds"]

Comment: Best would be to fetch it that way from the database.

Answer (score 5):

you can use `map` together with `Object.values` and `flat`

- map(i => Object.values(i)) - it creates array of arrays //[['HM'], ['McDons']]
- flat will create one level array

```js
const input = [
{
    "tenantName": "H&M"
},
{
    "tenantName": "McDonalds"
}
];

const result = input.map(i => Object.values(i)).flat()
console.log(result)
```

if you know that one item(object) of array always will have key `tenantName`
then you can use only `map`

```js
    const input = [
    {
        "tenantName": "H&M"
    },
    {
        "tenantName": "McDonalds"
    }
    ];

    const result = input.map(i => i.tenantName)
    console.log(result)
```

Comment: please correct me if I'm wrong, we need to do 2 operations here and this can be solved in just one, whats the tradeoff?

Comment: it depends on `key` if we know it or not

Comment: yes, and here the question included the array coming as a result of a query,  so no need of any overengineering imo, i've just noticed you edited your answer multiple time so it kinda explains, thanks though!

Comment: yes, I firsly added code, posted it , then added explanation for cases, methods

Comment: or is it not allowed?

Comment: no no, absolutely alright, just by the time I was writing my comment it didnt refresh that you updated hence my confusion, no biggie

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map`

```
const tenantArray = [ { "tenantName": "H&M" }, { "tenantName": "McDonalds" }].map(tenant => tenant.tenantName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.map() works well for this.

```js
var data = [
      {
        tenantName: "H&M",
      },
      {
        tenantName: "McDonalds",
      },
    ];


    function filterJSON(json){
    return json.map(i => i.tenantName);
    }

    console.log(filterJSON(data));
```